# 404 problem because of outdated config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9

I've purchased the MageBright Store Locator module. Uploaded all the files. Flushed cache, logged out and back in.

First I had a 404 problem because the config.xml was written in an outdated way. Fixed this.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-locator-extension-5.html (demo at bottom)

**Config.xml**:

0.1.0

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <gmapstrlocator>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magebright_Gmapstrlocator</module>
                <frontName>gmapstrlocator</frontName>
            </args>
        </gmapstrlocator>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Magebright_Gmapstrlocator after="Mage_Adminhtml">Magebright_Gmapstrlocator</Magebright_Gmapstrlocator>
                </modules>
            </args>
         </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**System.xml**:

Magebright Extensions
            101

```
    <gmapstrlocator  translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
    <tab>magebright</tab>
    <label>Store Locator</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <groups>

         <general translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>                
            <identifier translate="label">
                <label>Frontend Router</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </identifier>   
            <page_title translate="label">
                <label>Meta Title</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment></comment>
            </page_title>
            <meta_description translate="label">
                <label>Meta Description</label>
                <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment></comment>
            </meta_description> 
            <meta_keywords translate="label">
                <label>Meta Keywords</label>
                <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment></comment>
            </meta_keywords>                
            <page_heading translate="label">
                <label>Page Heading</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </page_heading>
            <page_subheading translate="label">
                <label>Page Sub Heading</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </page_subheading>

            <standard_lat translate="label">
                <label>Standard Latitude</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </standard_lat>             
            <standard_long translate="label">
                <label>Standard Longitude</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </standard_long>
            </fields>
         </general>

         <manage_links translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Links Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
            <header_enable translate="label">
                <label>Enable Header Link</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </header_enable>
            <header_text translate="label">
                <label>Header Link Label</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
                <depends><header_enable>1</header_enable></depends>
            </header_text>
            <footer_enable translate="label">
                <label>Enable Footer Link</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
            </footer_enable>
            <footer_text translate="label">
                <label>Footer Link Label</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
                <depends><footer_enable>1</footer_enable></depends>
            </footer_text>
            </fields>
         </manage_links>

         <layout_update translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Layout Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>21</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
            <page_column translate="label">
                <label>Select Layout</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_source_layoutupdate</source_model>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
            </page_column>              
            </fields>
         </layout_update>

         <manage_attribute translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Attributes Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>22</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
            <enable_filters translate="label">
                <label>Enable Attributes Filter</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </enable_filters>       
            <filter_text translate="label">
                <label>Attributes Filter Heading</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                 
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <depends><enable_filters>1</enable_filters></depends>
            </filter_text>              
            </fields>
         </manage_attribute>

         <manage_search translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Search Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>23</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
            <product translate="label">
                <label>Enable Search By Product</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </product>              
            <address translate="label">
                <label>Enable Search By Address, Zip Code, State</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </address>              
            </fields>
         </manage_search>

         <info_popup translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Map Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>24</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
            <button_text translate="label">
                <label>Get Direction Button Text</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </button_text>

            <marker_image translate="label">
                <label>Map Marker</label>
                <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                <backend_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_backend_image_marker</backend_model>
                <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">gmapstrlocator/marker</base_url>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment>Allowed file types: PNG, GIF, JPEG</comment>
            </marker_image>

            <bg_primary_image translate="label">
                <label>Mouse Hover Marker</label>
                <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                <backend_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_backend_image_bgprimary</backend_model>
                <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">gmapstrlocator/bgprimary</base_url>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment>Allowed file types: PNG, GIF, JPEG</comment>
            </bg_primary_image>

            <enable_mouseover_marker translate="label">
                <label>Enable Mouse Hover Marker</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                   
                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </enable_mouseover_marker>

            <enable_marker_numbers translate="label">
                <label>Enable Marker Numbers</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </enable_marker_numbers>

            <enable_sidebar_markers translate="label">
                <label>Enable Sidebar Markers</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </enable_sidebar_markers>

            <map_zoom translate="label">
                <label>Map Zoom</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment>Enter digit to set map zoom. For Ex.( 6, 8, 11)</comment>
            </map_zoom>
            <map_distance>
                <label>Map Distance</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <source_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_source_mapdistance</source_model>
                <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
            </map_distance>

            </fields>
         </info_popup>           
         <seo translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Search Engine Optimizations</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>25</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
                <url_suffix translate="label">
                        <label>URL Suffix</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <comment>(eg: .html)</comment>
            </url_suffix>
            </fields>
        </seo>  

        <image_settings translate="label">
            <label>Store Image Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>26</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            <fields>                        
                <image_width translate="label">
                        <label>Image Width</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                                
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </image_width>
                <image_height translate="label">
                        <label>Image Height</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                                
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </image_height>
            </fields>
        </image_settings>

    </groups>
    </gmapstrlocator>


</sections>
```

Comment: "Support seems gone from MageBright" > means you contacted them but they do not reply? :(

Comment: Please share you Magento  version ?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Yes thats right.

Comment: @Arunendra Version 1.9.2.4

Comment: Hi, I saw the edit of the question. Actually you got already answers here related to the first problem so I suggest to ask a new question with the new problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Arunendra already posted the correct link in his answer.

It's not just only related to the Magento version.

This is a problem of modules using an **outdated** way of defining and admin router related to the SUPEE-6788 patch.
It seems the extension was not adjusted for shops having the SUPEE-6788 patch.

Try to adjust the admin router as defined in the "APPSEC-1034, addressing bypassing custom admin URL" section of the [SUPEE-6788 technical details page](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details).

**Update** according to your config.xml update:

Actually you seem to have both, the old and new, definition of admin routers in your config.xml.

I would try to either just to remove the first block (the `<gmapstrlocatoradmin>...</gmapstrlocatoradmin>` block) or remove the first block and also update the 2nd block the following way:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Magebright_Gmapstrlocator after="Mage_Adminhtml">Magebright_Gmapstrlocator</Magebright_Gmapstrlocator_Override>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Hi Anna, I've added the related xml parts in the main image, to what should i change this to? Would be very welcome :3

Comment: See my update. That is my best guess.

Comment: It's not working, both ways. Can I share the package with you so you can take a look at it?

Comment: No, please don't. What needs also be checked and maybe adjusted are the system.xml menu entries or any calls where the module retrieves the URL.

Comment: Pretty bad you did not get any support from the extension vendor. For how long/how often did you try it?

Comment: This is a paid extension where the extension vendor obviously lacked support. You should try to report it to Magento as they are listed on Magento Connect.

Comment: I've seen on Facebook they are not responding to others, also people who ask their money back. It is a working module tho, seen many websites using it on google. But the code is a bit outdated, ill look for reporting them. Ill update the mainpost with the system.xml

Comment: There's also a adminhtml.xml

Comment: Update: ive edited the adminhtml.xml "gmapstrlocatoradmin" entries to  "adminhtml", now 404 doesn't show up anymore but just the back-end menu with blank space

Comment: So the 404 is gone. After these changes, do you maybe know why in the back-end only the menu and footer is showing up and center/main area is empty when I go to Store Locator > Manage Stores? There's also nothing to be found in the system/exception log.

Answer (score 1):

This extension support Magento version up-to 1.9.2 if you are using higher version of Magento then you need to update it's config file as per Magento SUPEE [see details here :](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Comment: Updated the thread. Changing xml helped the 404 error go away but didn't solve it completely.